# How to go back to previous window page after opening a pop-up page in ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to go back to previous window after opening a pop-up window page?

I have a page with a button, after a button is clicked a new pop-up window page appears. Inside that pop-up window has a button too and every time the user click that button it must go back to the previous window where it came from.

I used below vb.net code to open a pop-up window on button click

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(String), "uniqueKey", "PopupWindow('PopUp.aspx','myPop','1000','700')", True)
```

where PopupWindow is a javascript function.

I don't know what code to use on going back to window page. I tried several javascript and vb.net codes but it's not working.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do u want, u want to prev page in pop window or in the main window from where the pop is opened.

Comment: I want to go back to the main window form where the pop is opened sir

Comment: Then just close the pop up window using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it in viewstate/Session  and navigate it on Page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if( !IsPostBack )
     {
        ViewState["RefUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
     }
  }
```

and on close of popup

```
 object refUrl = ViewState["RefUrl"];
  if (refUrl != null)
      Response.Redirect((string)refUrl);
```

Also you can try in Javascript
javascript:history.go(-1)
and
window.history.back()

Comment: i tried it but it didn't go back to the previous window, instead the url opens in the pop-up window

Comment: Ok then try using Viewstate and session

Comment: that's what I used sir, the viewstate

Comment: just read your question again: 
1. Page have button
2. Clicking on button opens popup
3. There is button that when clicked, parent page should be seen

correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Are you trying something like this, if I am not wrong?
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close

Comment: Yeah..just like that Sir

Comment: Ok, then you can pull out code from above link and implement it in your code

Comment: Thanks Sir..ahm i have another question sir what if I closed the parent window before opening the pop-up window, will it re-open the parent window again if i click the button close in pop-up window?

Comment: Popup term is meant for Parent and Child window only. Popup have to be corresponded to its parent window. If window is closed then you need to pull out history from browser and reopen it (or save it in session and open a new page)